# preg_match on string and building then a new string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have the following strings:

```
Mo,Mi-Fr 9-19 Uhr, Di 8-19, Sa 9-18 Uhr

Mo-Mi+Fr 9-19, Do 8-19, Sa 9-14 Uhr

Mo,MI,Fr 9-20 Uhr<br>
DI,Do,Sa 8:30-20 Uhr

Mo Di Do Fr 9-19, Mi 8-19, Sa 9-16
```

I have to re-format these kind of strings like this:

```
Mo 9-19 Uhr, Mi-Fr 9-19 Uhr, Di 8-19, Sa 9-18 Uhr

Mo-Mi 9-19, Fr 9-19, Do 8-19, Sa 9-14 Uhr

Mo 9-20 Uhr, MI 9-20 Uhr, Fr 9-20 Uhr<br>
DI 8:30-20 Uhr, Do 8:30-20 Uhr, Sa 8:30-20 Uhr

Mo 9-19, Di 9-19, Do 9-19, Fr 9-19, Mi 8-19, Sa 9-16
```

Unfortunately, I am relatively inexperienced in dealing with regular expressions.

My idea was first make a preg_match and then create the string new.

Can someone help me?

Comment: _My idea was first make a preg_match and then create the string new._ Good idea, try it.

Comment: I don’t think it makes much sense trying to get the result using preg_replace to begin with. Use preg_match to gets this split into the parts, then write some script logic to rearrange those in the output format you need.

Comment: Ok. How can i match a string like this "Mo,Mi-Fr 9-19 Uhr". A little starter help would be really nice and helpful.

Comment: You need to make your own effort first, we are not here to write this for you. Site like https://regex101.com/ or https://www.regextester.com/ can help you get started and test stuff.

Comment: I don’t think this should be done using one “killer regex” either. Start by splitting this at the comma, then loop over the individual parts and split those at the space, so that you get the days and the time as separate components. Proceed splitting the day part from there …

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
([a-z]++(?:-[a-z]++)?+)\h*+[,+]?\h*+(?=(?:\h*+[,+]?\h*+[a-z]++(?:-[a-z]++)?+)+\h*+([0-9:-]++))
```

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/H9N4Uc/2/)